# How to remove Google Structure Data tags from page

Tags: magento2, structured-data

Magnento default adds following google structured data tags in every page by default.

> itemtype
>
> itemscope
>
> itemprop

I want to remove them. I found that you can place below code in your layout xml file.

```
<attribute name="itemtype" remove="true" />
<attribute name="itemscope" remove="true" />
```

But this is giving me error for my magento 2.2.6 as below.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'attribute', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed.
Line: 277
```

Also i tried below.

```
<attribute name="itemtype" value=""  />
<attribute name="itemscope" value="" />
```

But that too is also not working.
I can remove them using javascript but want to remove by server side only so that it never render to page.

Answer (score 0):

Exception occur because those attributes are not allowed when using `referenceBlock` and you should locate them in your code a remove them.

You need to check the available attributes for "referenceBlock" tag in:

`/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd`

the attributes allowed like:

```
<xs:attribute type="elementNameType" name="name" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="template" use="optional"/>
<xs:attribute type="xs:boolean" name="display" default="true" use="optional"/>
<xs:attribute type="xs:boolean" name="remove" use="optional"/>
```

This is why an exception is thrown in `/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php` (_initDom method).

Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11116

Comment: Thats okay, is there any solution available to get it done ?